# How to detect when someone joins the network environment

Tags: network-shares

I'm sharing my Internet connection with someone who's only occasionally online. When his PC is running, it's visible in the network environment.

How can I have my computer popup an alert if that user logs on to the network environment? I'd like to know when I can free some bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

In what way is the PC visible in the network environment?

Here's a very simple batch script which you could schedule to run repeatedly:

```
@ECHO OFF
NET VIEW | FIND "PCNAME" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 NET SEND %USERNAME% "Foo is here" > NUL
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for windows 7/8?